# C++: Conversion const uint8_t* to std::stringstream

Tags: c++, std

How can i convert a `const uint8_t*` back into a `stringstream`? Thank you

```
std::stringstream s1;
s1 << 4 << ' ' << 2 <<;
const uint8_t* sbuffer = (uint8_t*) s1.str().c_str();
int sbufferlength = s1.str().length();
std::stringstream s2 = //get stringstream from sbuffer    
int x, y;
s2 >> x >> y;
```

Comment: Uh, what are you trying to do? I smell an XY problem here.

Comment: I need the sbuffer as payload for an [ns3::Packet](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_packet.html). After the successful reception of a packet i access the payload with the method 'uint32_t CopyData (uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t size) const' and convert the buffer back to a stringstream. The 2 answers below are resulting in a stringstream with different values in comparison to the initial stringstream. The usage of a stringstream is just one idea to pack several variables in the payload of one packet. What would you recommend to create the payload buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: You are not capturing the address of the stringstream, you are receiving a pointer to part of it's internals, the c-string that it manages, and converting that to a unit8_t pointer.

So you can't just cast it back, instead what you need to do is create a second stringstream and construct it from your c-string array.

```
s2 << sbuffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate a `stringstream` with a `char table`, you can use `str(const string& s)` to do so.

In your case:

```
std::stringstream s2;
s2.str(string((char*)sbuffer,sbufferlength));
```

Or straight up, using the constructor:

```
std::stringstream s2(string((char*)sbuffer,sbufferlength));
```